# Can I sort my code using different function in selenium

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://demoqa.com/sortable");
var numberOne = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-  list']/div/div[1]"));
var numberTwo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[2]"));

var actions = new Actions(driver);
actions
     .ClickAndHold(numberTwo)
     .MoveToElement(numberOneOne)
     .MoveByOffset(0, 10)
     .Release()
     .Perform();
```

IList
This code helps me to change the position the numbers. But now iI want to (upgrade) him.

How I can do same things by using (IList)?

I using the example with sortable numbers from : http://demoqa.com/sortable

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're exactly asking for here. What do you mean by '(upgrade) him'.

I've put together a bit of code that will handle moving a list item to a different position, but using a method that is re-usable:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://demoqa.com/sortable");

            // Get the list of items (one to six)
            var listItems = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div"));

            // Use a method to specify what item to movem and where
            Sort(listItems, "One", "Three");
            Sort(listItems, "Three", "Six");

            _driver.Dispose();
        }

        private void Sort(ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list, string itemToMove, string itemToReplace)
        {
            var elToMove = list.First(a => a.Text == itemToMove);
            var elToReplace = list.First(a => a.Text == itemToReplace);

            var actions = new Actions(_driver);
            actions
                 .ClickAndHold(elToMove)
                 .MoveToElement(elToReplace)
                 .MoveByOffset(0, 10)
                 .Release()
                 .Perform();
        }
    }
```

Comment: to take all the numbers in some list and after to move them by index? I dont know even if this is possible, but just asking, thanks